# Switching dataframe integers to string so i can add text like '$' and '5.78 / Million' into the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, numpy

I made a dataframe with all the necessary information, however, my manager wants me to remove decimals from all entries except col['REVENUE'] x index['Volume']. Aka keep 5.78 and remove the trailing zero from everything else.

I also need to add in text like '$' and 'mm' to some values like "5,388 MM" and "$2,965,773."

To put it nicely, I am lost in the sauce about what to do now. Thanks for your help.

If you could please break it down to baby steps, even if its just parts of the problem, I would be immensly grateful.

I tried converting some values into strings, but that then gave me an error message when i tried to print the df. I included some of the code up to hopefully make things a bit more clear. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify this question!!!

```
RFQ_count = df['STATUS'].count()
# RFQ_count = str(RFQ_count)
# print(type(RFQ_count))
Vol_RAMT = df['R-AMT'].sum()
Vol_RAMT = int(round(Vol_RAMT))
DV01 = df['DV01'].sum() 
DV01 = int(round(DV01))

DF_data = {
    'Total': [RFQ_count, Vol_RAMT, DV01],
                   'Count': [hit_count, hit_count_volume, hit_ount_DV01],
                    'Ratio1 %': [hit_ratio_count, hit_ratio_volume, hit_ratio_DV01],
                    'Count': [cover_plus_count, cover_plus_volume, cover_plus_DV01],
                    'Ratio2 %': [cover_count_ratio, cover_volume_ratio, cover_DV01_ratio],
                   'Wins': [tie_win_count, tie_win_volume, tie_win_DV01],
                   'Away': [tie_away_count, tie_away_volume, tie_away_DV01],
                    'Ratio3 %': [int(round((tie_win_count / tie_away_count) * 100)), 
                                    int(round((tie_win_volume / tie_away_volume) * 100)), 
                                    int(round((tie_win_DV01 / tie_away_DV01) * 100))],
                    'Revenue': [rev_count, rev_vol, rev_DV01],
                                         }                       
                        

index_labels=["Count", "Volume", "DV01"] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(DF_data, index=index_labels).round(2).style.format("{:,}")
# df1['RFQ Total'] = df1['RFQ Total'].astype(str) + '$'
print(type(DF_data))
df1`
```

[image: This is the output table]

Comment: What's the printing error?  Converting ints to strings for a pandas cell should be easy - just save the string form to the cell.  pandas uses plain python strings, and `object` dtype for the column (with any strings)

Comment: Conversion to string should generally not be done on the frame. This is a formatting exercise, not a conversion exercise.

Comment: What is the final rendered destination for these data?

Comment: it will be going to a PDF

Comment: Using some intermediate format? HTML? Or a different rendering library?

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question. I am learning how this works as I go, as you can probably infer. This will get saved and converted to PDF, in the most efficient and normal manner, whatever that is. I am far from being at that decision point, but open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

With no other context, the preferable thing to do is avoid converting in the frame itself, and use formatters instead. This string can be put in a PDF in a pre-formatted block.

```py
import locale
from functools import partial

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'Total': (785, 5_388, 2_965_773),
        'Count': (518, 3_729, 2_120_275),
        'Ratio1': (0.27, 0.30, 0.31),
        'Ratio2': (0.66, 0.69, 0.71),
        'Wins': (100, 906, 419_929),
        'Away': (82, 658, 310_545),
        'Ratio3': (1.22, 1.38, 1.35),
        'Revenue': (9_268.00, 578.00, 1_000.00),
    },
    index=('Count', 'Volume', 'DV01'),
)

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, '')
print(
    df.to_string(
        formatters={
            'Total': '{:,.0f}'.format,
            'Count': '{:,.0f}'.format,
            'Wins': '{:,.0f}'.format,
            'Away': '{:,.0f}'.format,
            'Ratio1': '{:.0%}'.format,
            'Ratio2': '{:.0%}'.format,
            'Ratio3': '{:.0%}'.format,
            'Revenue': partial(locale.currency, grouping=True),
        }
    )
)
```

```
           Total     Count Ratio1 Ratio2    Wins    Away Ratio3   Revenue
Count        785       518    27%    66%     100      82   122% $9,268.00
Volume     5,388     3,729    30%    69%     906     658   138%   $578.00
DV01   2,965,773 2,120,275    31%    71% 419,929 310,545   135% $1,000.00
```